# QML Word wrap and TextArea and Margins

Tags: qt, qml

How can i make my TextArea word wrap the text area and auto adjust it's height to show the available text in the TextArea? Secondly how can i remove the odd spacing seen in my image attached.

This is what i have now:

[image]

This is what I desire:

[image]

**QML Code:**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Frame {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    anchors.fill: parent

    ListView {
        implicitWidth: parent.width
        implicitHeight: parent.height
        clip: true

        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {
                description: "Wash the car this could be a really long message with some multiline support we will see how it works."
            }
            ListElement {
                description: "Fix the car"
            }
            ListElement {
                description: "Sell the car"
            }
            ListElement {
                description: "Wash the car this could be a really long message with some multiline support we will see how it works. This should word wrap quite a lot of times."
            }
            ListElement {
                description: "Fix the car"
            }
            ListElement {
                description: "Sell the car"
            }
            ListElement {
                description: "Wash the car"
            }
            ListElement {
                description: "Fix the car"
            }
            ListElement {
                description: "Sell the car"
            }
        }

        delegate: RowLayout {
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            Rectangle {
                id: newsicon
                width: 16
                height: 16
                color: "steelblue"
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
            }

            ColumnLayout {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                spacing: 0

                TextArea {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
                    id: messageText
                    text: model.description
                    wrapMode: TextEdit.WordWrap
                    readOnly: true
                    textMargin: 0.0
                    background: null
                }
                Label {
                    id: dateText
                    text: "Dec 20, 2019"
                    font.italic: true
                    font.pointSize: 8
                    color: "grey"
                }
            }
        }

        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            active: true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your delegate top item `RowLayout` should set `width: parent.width` instead of `Layout.fillWidth: true` (there is no layout above the delegate)

Comment: how do i remove the padding around the text area?

Comment: Set the `padding` to 0, or even less if you want really compact. You can also use `leftPadding`, `rightPadding`, `bottomPadding` and `topPadding` individually

Comment: i set padding and margin to 0 and it didn't change the appearance at all.

Comment: you were right! that fixed it :)